# What makes Yarn encore dev take so long to build? Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

#### Summary of all below details (including edits)

Encore builds take very long to compile and the webpage takes very long to load. Chances of them working as expected is very rare, very random. The main issue is `.addEntry()`, `app.js` and css work fine but all other JS does not. What exactly the issue is or how to fix it is unknown. Currently assuming it's something with a version update. But I dont know what package it might be.

---

#### Details

Since last week my Encore takes very long to build. Whenever I use `yarn encore dev` or `yarn encore dev --watch`, it will 90% of the time run very slowly. The other 10% it builds fast. When viewing my page, another 90% of the time it loads all files except one (sometimes two) JS file. It takes 1 to 2.5 minutes to load.

- Im using Yarn v1.22.5.
- Symfony 4.4
- Windows 10
- Visual studio code v1.70.2
- Auto save file when unfocussed from VSC
- VSC its command prompt (terminal) to run commands

Composer.lock encore version:

```json
"name": "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle",
"version": "v1.11.1",
```

yarn.lock:

```
"@symfony/webpack-encore@^1.0.0":
version "1.1.2"
```

Looks like `webpack-encore` is at an old version (newest is 3.1.0). Not sure if I can upgrade but I don't see the need. Im not sure, but this should mean there have not been updates to encore for me for a long time right? Since 1.1.2 is the latest version, after that comes 2.0.0, which it doesn't take because of ^ at ^1.0.0.

package.json:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "file-loader": "6.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

Webpack.config.js:

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',

        // optional target path, relative to the output dir
        //to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

        // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',

        // only copy files matching this pattern
        //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
    })

    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('navbar_js', './assets/js/navbar.js')
    .addEntry('translate_months_js', './assets/js/translate_months.js')
    .addEntry('account_management_js', './assets/js/account_management.js')
    .addEntry('account_management_cu_js', './assets/js/account_management_cu.js')
    .addEntry('closed_days_js', './assets/js/closed_days.js')
    .addEntry('check_weeks_js', './assets/js/check_weeks.js')
    .addEntry('time_registration_js', './assets/js/time_registration.js')
    .addEntry('time_registration_day_js', './assets/js/time_registration_day.js')
    .addEntry('time_registration_add_hours_js', './assets/js/time_registration_add_hours.js')
    .addEntry('time_registration_clock_in_js', './assets/js/time_registration_clock_in.js')
    .addEntry('annual_review_js', './assets/js/annual_review.js')
    .addEntry('users_overview_hours_js', './assets/js/users_overview_hours.js')
    .addEntry('add_absent_js', './assets/js/add_absent.js')
    .addEntry('user_profile_basis_js', './assets/js/user_profile_basis.js')
    .addEntry('automatic_clocking_js', './assets/js/automatic_clocking.js')
    .addEntry('previous_holiday_hours_js', './assets/js/previous_holiday_hours.js')
    .addEntry('corrections_js', './assets/js/corrections.js')
    .addEntry('system_absent_js', './assets/js/system_absent.js')
    .addEntry('system_absent_cu_js', './assets/js/system_absent_cu.js')
    .addEntry('access_to_settings_js', './assets/js/access_to_settings.js')
    .addStyleEntry('table', './assets/styles/table.css')
    .addStyleEntry('navbar', './assets/styles/navbar.css')
    .addStyleEntry('modal', './assets/styles/modal.css')
    .addStyleEntry('create', './assets/styles/create.css')
    .addStyleEntry('register_css', './assets/styles/register.css')
    .addStyleEntry('user_profile_basis_css', './assets/styles/user_profile_basis.css')
    .addStyleEntry('annual_review_css', './assets/styles/annual_review.css')
    .addStyleEntry('users_overview_hours_css', './assets/styles/users_overview_hours.css')
    .addStyleEntry('time_registration_css', './assets/styles/time_registration.css')
    .addStyleEntry('time_registration_add_hours_css', './assets/styles/time_registration_add_hours.css')
    .addStyleEntry('previous_holiday_hours_css', './assets/styles/previous_holiday_hours.css')
    .addStyleEntry('corrections_css', './assets/styles/corrections.css')
    .addStyleEntry('system_management_css', './assets/styles/system_management.css')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Message when running `yarn encore dev --watch`:

```
MY_PROJECT>yarn encore dev --watch
yarn run v1.22.5
$ MY_PROJECT\node_modules\.bin\encore dev --watch
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Running webpack ...

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 106373ms                                                                                                                                                          15:14:50
 I  74 files written to public\build
webpack compiled successfully
Notifications are disabled
Reason: DisabledForApplication Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.
Command Line: MY_PROJECT\node_modules\node-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoretoast-x64.exe -pipeName \\.\pipe\notifierPipe-a79e1c68-6b11-4441-9c50-cff84d27e9c0 -p MY_PROJECT\node_modules\webpack-notifier\logo.png -m "Build successful" -t "Webpack Encore"
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 168ms                                                                                                                                                             15:14:51
 I  74 files written to public\build
webpack compiled successfully
```

I have tried running `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` but it keeps asking the same after execution. I also tried deleting my build files. **Which took at least 5 minutes to delete,** while it was just 5mb it had to delete. I tried deleting a file of 10mb and it got removed instandly, so it should not be my pc. After I deleted the files, yarn encore ran with normal speed. But then the second time I run encore it takes ages again.

I also tried to clear cache trough `php bin/console cache:clear` (both dev and prod) with no success. Also tried to clear local browser cache and yarn its cache. Everytime I do this, the first time I run encore, it builds normally. But then the second time it breaks.

It leads me to think encore has some issues with overriding/deleting the files when run.

When using `encore dev --watch` it takes very long to load any webpage. The basic files load but some (random possibly) JS files called `vendor-node-...-custom_js_file_linked_in_webpack` take 1 to 2.5 minutes to load. Just using `encore dev` makes pages load as normal.

I also tried to run encore without symfony server active, but it makes no difference.

How can I possibly fix this?

**Edit 1, some extra things i've tried:**

- Run both symfony server and yarn encore in a seperate CMD console. Tested both in VSC and just plain Windows CMD. No success or any differences.
- Cloned my repo in seperate folder, the latest version of dev branch. Exactly the same issues arise.
- Tried to not use `symfony server:start` but instead use `php -S localhost:8000`. Same issues persisted.
- Tried running an old branch (2 months old) but the same issues arise.

I have come to a point now where `yarn encore dev` and `--watch` both run fast most of the times. But then when loading the actual page it loads all files except 1 (sometimes 2) JS file: `vendors-node_modules_symfony_stimulus-bridge_dist_index_js-node_modules_core-js_internals_str-95febb.js`. Also, the moment the page is loading this JS file the loading circle (left top in chrome tab) is blue instead of gray. Indicating it is my pc running the last bit, not the server sending things to me. When this circle is blue, basicly everything I do on this laptop is extremely slow. Other websites wont load and one time I could not even open taskmanager...

It feels really random as to when encore works. Its about 90/100 times not working. Either the building proces takes years or loading my page.

**Edit 2:**

So far I found out that it is `.addEntry()` who is doing the harm. Except for app.js, which is loadable. Any of my custom JS is most of the time not loading without a delay of 17-190s. I can load all css files (addStyleEntry). Within app.js, Fontawesome loads fine too.

Average loading time without the .addEntry() is 3 seconds. The webpage itself loads fast too.

Comment: You said "Since last week", what did you change recently ? New yarn version ? New pacakges ? Anything at all that could lead to such a drastic decrease in performance ?

Comment: @DylanKas hi, I did not change anything except for adding one JS file to webpack.config.js. When I did this no issues arise. But when I committed my files to github (me going merging feature into dev -> dev into master) it seems to start getting issues. I remember my yarn was still watching while I did this process. But I have been doing this since I started (1 year ago). And I deleted my build files and recreated them with yarn encore so I dont see how that caused issues.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my packages and moving to Symfony 5.4 (instead of 4.4) fixed the issue. Im not sure what package or thing exactly broke my webpack.